# Get Spinner Selection after dynamically filling it with Parse.com

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-spinner, getselection

I am trying to get the spinner selection after it has been filled using Parse.com

This is what I get when I use
    `uniSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`
This is what I get:

```
com.parse.ParseObject@"Some numbers here, not the ID stored in parse"
```

The below code also produces the same outcome:

```
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "test: " +
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here is my code that creates the spinner:

```
 public void uniSpinnerSetup()
{
    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("University");
            return query;
        }
    };

    uniSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.uniSpinner);

    ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
    adapter.setTextKey("name");
    uniSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    uniSpinner.setSelection(1);
    uniSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new mySpinnerListener());
}

class mySpinnerListener implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "test: " +
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do nothing.
    }

}
```

I've looked high and low to try and resolve it, have not found a solution! Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Correct answer is in the comments sections)

Move your adapter out as a field variable and get your object using that:

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter;

 public void uniSpinnerSetup()
{
    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("University");
            return query;
        }
    };

    uniSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.uniSpinner);

    adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
    adapter.setTextKey("name");
    uniSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    uniSpinner.setSelection(1);
    uniSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new mySpinnerListener());
}

class mySpinnerListener implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ParseObject theSelectedObject = adapter.getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "test: " +
                theSelectedObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do nothing.
    }

}
```

Comment: That produces the exact same result: `com.parse.ParseObject@"Some numbers here, not the ID stored in parse"`

Comment: Ok, then maybe that change was not needed. What happens if you do: `theSelectedObject.getObjectId()` or `theSelectedObject .get("name")` in the toast?

Comment: oh my, thank you so much! That actually does exactly what I require and gets the university name instead of a reference (or whatever it is). Thanks again :)

Comment: Just for anyone else with a similar problem, I used the `theSelectedObject .get("name")`

Comment: No problem :) think you can move back to the code as is in your question. Seems just to be the `toString()` that is not returning what you expect.